# Scrape only visible elements with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape some web-sites with Nokogiri like this

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open(url_path))
```

When I get this HTML I search for a value, but Nokogiri selects all elements including hidden ones which I don't need.

How do I get only `display: block` elements or exclude `display: none`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to tell us more about what you're trying to do. As is we're going to have to cobble together imaginary HTML and code to it. Provide a minimal HTML example, minimal sample code showing how you're trying to do it, and what you want to capture. Without that we're guessing what you're after and that wastes our time and yours, so help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify to ignore hidden elements like this:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url_path))
page.at_xpath("//input[not (@type='hidden')]") # get all visible input fields
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers"
 page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))  
 page.css('td b a').each do |line|
   puts line.text  # "Spanish"        
 end
```

Comment: If 'td b a' are hidden elements they will still be scrapped, and in that case it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: This doesn't match the OPs description of the problem. It would return text inside bolded anchors in cells. Please describe why the OP would want to use this instead of simply tossing out code.